# Laravel table migrations doesn't exist after install

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I'm going crazy!

I'm trying to install laravel 9 with filament TALLkit.

So I install Laravel, Limevire e filament by composer.

Now i'm running `php artisan migrate:install --database=mysql` to install table migrations. Watching mysql tables it exists.

But when i run `php artisan migrate`, migration table is removed and this error happens:

> Loading stored database schema:
> /srv/www/mysite/current/database/schema/mysql-schema.dump Loaded
> stored database schema. (7.89ms)
>
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'mydb.migrations' doesn't exist (SQL: select `migration` from
> `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc)
>
> at
> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
> 708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
> 709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
> 710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
> 711▕         catch (Exception $e) {   ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
> 713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 714▕             );
> 715▕         }
> 716▕     }
>
> ```
>   +27 vendor frames    28  artisan:37
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> ```
>
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

Comment: Are you sure it is removed? Why do you explicitly pass `--database=mysql` to the first command and not to the second as well?

Comment: You probably have the wrong `DB_CONNECTION` or `DB_DATABASE` setting, or are you using multiple database connections?

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan migrate` without Filament, just with a fresh Laravel app ?

Comment: doing php artisan schema:dump after migrate:install fix the problem